# Unwanted white space at page header when clicking on the INPUT - Safari on Iphone

Tags: javascript, iphone, input, mobile-safari, whitespace

Reproducing the error on google's website:

[image]

When the input is first clicked, nothing happens and everything is normal:

[image]

When I focus on the input and the keyboard appears and then press away to lose focus, it gets the following error:

[image]

Repeat focusing and pressing outward a few times like so:

[image]

This error only occurs on safari on iphone. My website also has the same error. How to fix this error?